# Dedekind modular law

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Dedekind modular law. If $A,B,C$ are subgroups of a group $G$ with $A \subseteq B$ then $A(B \cap C) = B \cap AC$.

Below is what I want to prove.
Let K be a finite group with $K = LH$, where $L,H$ are subgroups of $K$ with relatively prime orders. If $U$ is a maximal subgroup of $L$ then $UH = HU$.
Proof:

$HU = HU \cap LH = (HU \cap L)H = (H \cap L)UH = UH$

Is my proof true?

Comment: I edited your question but your should really take the time to learn how to properly write the mathematical symbols that you want to use. It's basically a matter of inserting some "$" signs here and there and it really improves the legibility of your post.

Comment: I will try to learn.

Comment: How did you get $HU\cap LH = (HU\cap L)H$?

Comment: I put $A=H$, $B=HU$, $C=L$ and used the law in the following form $B \cap CA=(B \cap C)A$

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not know that I was assuming $UH$ is a group already in my proof.

Answer (score 3):

There is a mistake in your proof.  When you state Dedekind's rule above, you assume $A, B, C$ are subgroups of a group.  So, to get your second equality using Dedekind's rule you assume $B= HU$ is a group, but that's what you are trying to prove. (Recall, $UH = HU$ if and only if $UH$ is a group.)