# $NH=KN\;$ and $\;H\cap N=K \cap N$ imply $H=K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let be $G$ a group and $H$ and $K$ two subgroups such that  $H\leq K \leq G$.

Let be $N\trianglelefteq G$. How can I prove that the relationions

$NH=KN\;$ and $\;H\cap N=K \cap N$ imply $H=K$?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply [Dedekind's Modular Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131798/dedekind-modular-law): if $H \leq K$, $NH=KN$ and $H \cap N = K \cap N$, then
$$H=H(H \cap N)=H(K \cap N)= K \cap NH= K \cap KN=K.$$

Comment: What's happend with the hypothesis that $N\trianglelefteq G$? Don't was used?

Comment: That is an excellent question! Yes it was used in a subtle way: the Dedekind Modular Law is about subgroups, not merely subsets. And $HN$ is a subgroup, because $N$ is normal. If $N$ wouldn't be normal, then $HN$ is not necessarily a subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**   $H/H \cap N\cong HN/N=KN/N\cong K/K\cap N$

Comment: I know this is an old one, but still worth a shot. I tried doing it using the map  $\varphi (h) = hN$ but I'm having trouble with showing that it's indeed a homomorphism.