# Question on the product of normal subgroups, theorem from a book

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups, proof-explanation

The following theorem is taken from the german book *Theorie der endlichen Gruppen* by Kurzweil/Stellmacher. I am highly suspicious about a claim and its proof from the chapter 1.6 on products of groups, and just want to know if this is justified and if my alternate reasoning works.

First a direct translation of the theorem and its proof.

> Let $G$ be the product of normal subgroups $G_1, \ldots, G_n$. Let
>   $$
>  Z_i := G_i \cap \prod_{j\ne i} G_j, \quad i = 1, \ldots, n.
> $$ 
>   Then
>   $$
>  G / \cap_{i=1}^n Z_i \cong G_1/Z_1 \times \ldots \times G_n/Z_n.
> $$
>   *Proof.* For $g \in G$ we have $g_i \in G_i$ with
>   $$
>  g = g_1\cdots g_n.
> $$
>   Because the subgroups $G_1, \ldots, G_n$ are normal, for $i = 1,\ldots, n$ the mapping
>   $$
>  \beta_i : G \to G/Z_i \quad \mbox{with}\quad g \mapsto g_i Z_i
> $$
>   is well-defined and a homomorphism with $\operatorname{Kern}(\beta_i) = Z_i$.
>   Then
>   $$
>  \alpha : G \to G/Z_1 \times \ldots G/Z_n \mbox{ with }
>  g \mapsto (g_1Z_1, \ldots, g_nZ_n)
> $$
>   is a homomorphism with
>   $$
>  \operatorname{Kern}(\alpha) = \bigcap_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Kern}(\beta_i) = \bigcap_{i=1}^n Z_i.
> $$
>   Hence the claim follows from the fundamental homomorphism theorem. $\square$

First I believe the correct claim should be
$$
 G / \prod_{i=1}^n Z_i \cong G_1/Z_1 \times \ldots \times G_n/Z_n.
$$
After a close look at the proof, I am suspicious about the claim that the kernel of $\beta_i$ is $Z_i$. This would be the case for the projection map $g \mapsto gZ_i$, but here we pick out an element from some product decomposition, hence for example $g_1 \in G_1$ would also be mapped to $1\cdot Z_2$
by $\beta_2$ as $g_1 = g_1 \cdot 1$ with $1 \in G_2$. To be more specific I believe the kernel should be
$$
 \operatorname{Kern}(\beta_i) = Z_i \cup \prod_{j\ne i} G_j = \prod_{j\ne i} G_j.
$$
Hence following the proof we would get
$$
 \operatorname{Kern}(\alpha) = \bigcap_{i=1}^n \left( \prod_{j\ne i} G_j \right)
$$
Now if we fix $i \in \{1,\ldots, n\}$ then
$$
 Z_i \le \prod_{j \ne k} G_j
$$
for any other $k \in \{1,\ldots, n\}$, hence $Z_1 \cdots Z_n \subseteq \operatorname{Kern}(\alpha)$. The converse implication is also valid, but this is a tedious chain of applications of [Dedekinds law for groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131798/dedekind-modular-law),
for example $Z_1 Z_2 Z_3 = (G_1 \cap G_2 G_3)(G_2 \cap G_1 G_3)(G_3\cap G_1G_2) = G_1G_2 \cap G_1G_3 \cap G_2 G_3$. Hence $\operatorname{Kern}(\alpha) = \prod_{i=1}^n Z_i$.

But there is also a more direct way to see this
\begin{align*}
 g = g_1 \ldots g_n \in \operatorname{Kern}(\alpha)
 & \Leftrightarrow g_1 \in Z_1, \ldots, g_n \in Z_n \\
 & \Leftrightarrow g \in Z_1 \ldots Z_n.
\end{align*}

Seems to be quite a subtle point, and actually it came to my mind in later chapters related to components, the generalized Fitting subgroup and the layer of a finite group where this theorem and implications for central products where used. And some arguments in the book confused me a little bit, hence it would be kind if you could help me resolve my confusion. Is it the case that the theorem is wrong? And is my reasoning correct then?

Comment: I guess for a $g=g_1\dots g_n$, we get $gZ_i=g_iZ_i$, hence $\beta_i$ *is* the canonical quotient map.

Comment: Okay, as far as I see this would give $$ \bigcap_{i=1}^n Z_i = \prod_{i=1}^n Z_i $$ hence these equal all $Z_i$ for each $i=1,\ldots, n$, which seems quite odd to me...

Comment: Hmm.. I tend to believe you're right. After all, $g_i^{-1}g\notin G_i$ in general, hence $\notin Z_i$ either, so my guess is indeed not justified.

Comment: @Berci Yes, also surely $Z_i \le G_j$, but I do not guess we would have equality here, which would also be implied by your comment.

Comment: It is unclear why $\cap Z_i = \prod Z_i$? As long as at least two $Z_i$'s are distinct,say $Z_1\neq Z_2$, then $Z_1\cap Z_2$ is strictly smaller than at least one of them; whereas $Z_1Z_2$ is larger than (may b equal to) both of them and you can see that $Z_1\cap Z_2$ is proper subgroup of $Z_1Z_2$.

Comment: @Beginner Under the hypothesis of what Berci said and what I have written in the question this inequality is implied. I also doubt that it is true.